# Why is "issued" the answer to "Fire corners if one-a-side matches haven't begun"?

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

Why is "issued" the answer to "Fire corners if one-a-side matches haven't begun"?
This was published in the NZ Herald cryptic crossword on 8th December 2020.

Answer (score 18):

The answer is *not* ISSUED, no matter what some websites on the internet may say.

I found what I think is the same crossword in another, older New Zealand publication. The crossing words give I-G-E- for this space, and the answer is INGLES. Definition is "fire corners", wordplay is SINGLES without its first letter.

Comment: Fantastic answer — great case of questioning assumptions in the question.  Just to expand a little on one point that may not be transparent to many readers: *INGLE* is a fairly rare term for a recessed or partially-enclosed fireplace area (hence “fire corner”), probably better-known in the longer form *INGLENOOK*.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! I spent a while trying to find any possible way to get ISSUED out of the clue and couldn't, so my options were to question assumptions in the question or to question my own infallibility. Obviously the latter was out of the question, so I had to do the former.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation! Now I'm puzzled by the published answer linked to INGLES and IGNORANT in the same crossword : Clue for 4 down : Angry American returns to stand in Piccadilly Circus. Ans : EROS...why is it EROS???? something to do with 'sore' ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. "Sore" means "angry" in US English. Put that backwards and you get EROS, and there's a famous statue of Eros in Piccadilly Circus in London. Well, strictly speaking it's a statue of _Anteros_ but everyone calls it "Eros".

Comment: Wonderful answer, thanks Gareth!

Comment: @Dan If this answer answered your question (which it looks like it did) you should click the little green checkmark thing, which will give me some Meaningless Internet Points. (It will give you some too, so that question-askers are motivated to indicate which answers were useful to them.)